# Not able to launch PyCharm on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, 17.04, pycharm

I  downloaded the .tar.gz package and extracted it in a folder, now when I open pycharm.sh all it opens is a script in gedit. What else should I do?

Comment: you aught to do `chmod +x pycharm.sh && ./pycharm.sh`

Comment: @pomsky it is marked exectuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should open it from the terminal `ctrl+alt+t`,

then
`cd ~/pycharm-location; ./bin/pycharm.sh`

then add a launcher from Tools menu.